# How to send signal to docker compose to stop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, docker-compose, package.json

I need to stop docker or docker-compose by stoping my nodejs app with Ctrl+C,
it means docker is up and down by nodejs .

i add start script to up docker-compose before nodejs but i can't figure that how to stop after nodejs stoping?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear.

From my understanding I hope this is what you want..

```
docker-compose stop <service-name>
```